# Responsive Mobile Menu and Javascript -- requesting opinions, critiques

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, menu

I've been doing a lot of reading on different ways to implement a responsive mobile drop-down menu. CSS only solutions seem to be a bit clunky to me, but I hate to rely on javascript for anything  as essential as a navigation menu. What I came up with is to use javascript, but rather than hide the menu in the css, I hide it in the script so that it will be visible to people without javascript enabled. What I need to know is if there are any issues with this method (other than the fact that the menu is always expanded without js) that I've overlooked. Does this seem like a reasonable solution? Did I do anything glaringly wrong here? Thanks very much for any and all feedback! [Here is the link.](http://www.granawebservices.com/downloads/template2/)

Comment: Where is the dropdown menu? .. oh I see, you need to make your window tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting `display: none` in JavaScript you can add a class that does that instead.

```
#nav.hidden { display: none; }
```

It think it's reasonable to do this in JavaScript for the reasons you mentioned.